# Diferencia en horas, minutos y segundos con un Shell

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

¡Hola buen día!

Tengo un inconveniente para poder mostrar el tiempo que tardo en ejecutarse mi shell. Actualmente lo tengo así, sirve para cuando no tarda más de 1 hr pero después de eso me muestra números negativos o no coincide con el tiempo de ejecución total.

```
#!/bin/bash

start_time=`date +"%T"`
start_hour=`date +"%H"`
start_minute=`date +"%M"`
start_second=`date +"%S"`

... (cálculos y ejecuciones de mi shell)

end_time=`date +"%T"`
end_hour=`date +"%H"`
end_minute=`date +"%M"`
end_second=`date +"%S"`

elapsed_hour=`expr $end_hour - $start_hour`
elapsed_minute=`expr $end_minute - $start_minute`
elapsed_second=`expr $end_second - $start_second`

echo "EL PROCESO DEMORO $elapsed_hour HRS CON $elapsed_minute MINS Y $elapsed_second SEGS EN EJECUTARSE."

exit;
```

En una ejecución que demoro 01:33:54 me mostraba: "El proceso demoro 2 hrs con -26 mins y -6 segs en ejecutarse"

Siguiendo los consejos de Steven Burgos, lo adapte de la siguiente manera:

```
start_time=`date +"%T"` 
end_time=`date +"%T"` 

start_seconds=$(date -d "$start_time" +%s) 
end_seconds=$(date -d "$end_time" +%s) 
datediff=$((end_seconds - start_seconds)) 

elapsed_time=UTC date -d @$datediff +%H:%M:%S 
elapsed_hours=$(date -d "$elapsed_time" +%H) 
elapsed_minutes=$(date -d "$elapsed_time" +%M) 
elapsed_seconds=$(date -d "$elapsed_time" +%S) 

echo "EL PROCESO DEMORO $elapsed_hours HRS CON $elapsed_minutes MINS Y $elapsed_seconds SEGS EN EJECUTARSE"
```

Pero todas mis variables **"elapsed"** están en ceros.

Por lo que decidí cambiar la manera del cálculo de la siguiente manera:

```
elapsed_time=$(date -d @$datediff +%H:%M:%S)
elapsed_hours=$((datediff/3600))
elapsed_minutes=$(((datediff % 3600)/60))
elapsed_seconds=$((datediff % 60))
```

El mensaje que me imprime es **"EL PROCESO DEMORO 0 HRS CON 2 MINS Y 0 SEGS EN EJECUTARSE."** lo cual es correcto. Pero mi variable **"elapsep_time"** tiene el valor de **"18:02:00"**.

¿Cómo podría hacer esa correcta resta en las horas de inicio y fin para que me muestre correctamente la misma?

¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Una idea de muchas: Hallar la diferencia en segundos de los dos tiempos, hallar la parte entera de dividir entre 3600 (horas), al residuo hallarle la parte entera de dividirlo entre 60 (minutos) y el residuo de eso son los segundos.

Comment: estoy de acuerdo con @Alfabravo. Si una cosa pasa a las 17:59 y otra a las 18:00, no tiene sentido decir que la diferencia es de 1 hora y -59 minutos, sino que es 1 minuto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final pude solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
#!/bin/bash

start_time=`date +"%T"`

... (cálculos y ejecuciones de mi shell)

end_time=`date +"%T"`
start_seconds=$(date -d "$start_time" +%s)
end_seconds=$(date -d "$end_time" +%s)
datediff=$((end_seconds - start_seconds))

elapsed_time=$(date -d @$datediff -u +%H:%M:%S)
elapsed_hours=$((datediff/3600))
elapsed_minutes=$(((datediff % 3600)/60))
elapsed_seconds=$((datediff % 60))

echo "HORA INICIO: $start_time"
echo "HORA FIN: $end_time"
echo "ELAPSED TIME: $elapsed_time"
echo ""
echo "EL PROCESO DEMORO $elapsed_hour HRS CON $elapsed_minute MINS Y $elapsed_second SEGS EN EJECUTARSE."

exit;
```

Con ello puedo ver tanto el tiempo de ejecución en formato *HH:MM:SS* con la variable `time_elapsed` y leerlo con un texto específico al separarlo en variables de horas, minutos y segundos.

Seguro hay una forma más sencilla, pero dejo esto por aquí por si a alguien también le sirve esta solución como a mí.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil, ya que [el usuario "Comunidad" se encarga de revivir la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215/qu%c3%a9-sucede-con-las-preguntas-que-tienen-respuestas-validas-pero-no-son-marcadas/1452) cada cierto tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba esto:

Los valores $1 - $2 son las fechas que capturas como cadenas con el comando date. De preferencia recomiendo que almacenes los valores en variables distintas para que puedas hacer el cálculo.

```
fec_ini=$(date -d "$1" +%s)
fec_fin=$(date -d "$2" +%s)
diff=$((fec_fin-fec_ini))
total=UTC date -d @$diff +%H:%M:%S
echo $total
```

Saludos,

Comment: @DiegoQuiroz por favor, el código ponlo en tu pregunta, editándola y **añadiendo** lo que intentes con sus correspondientes errores. En los comentarios ya ves que es imposible leer código